# UnmappedInstanceError with session.add() in tests sqlalchemy + postgresql + Plone 4.3

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, plone, plone-4.x

Kindly help: in a Plone product, unittests of tables without the full db setup works but when trying to include db for testing the following error happened. This is a Plone 4.3 product using sqlalchemy+postgresql.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", ... in run testMethod()
File "/home/....../tests/test_model.py", ..., in test_createClient
(ses, client) = createClient()
File "/home/...../tests/test_model.py", ..., in createClient
session.add(client1)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",.., in add
UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'my.product.model.Client' is not mapped
```

Seems table instance (client1) was not created for sqlalchemy session to add. Here's partial client table:

```
class Client(BaseObject):
    __tablename__ = 'client'

    id = schema.Column(types.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = schema.Column(types.String(50))

    def client_name(self):
        return self.name
```

the tested code in test_model.py:

```
def createClient():
    session = Session()
    client1 = model.Client(name=u"ACME",)
    session.add(client1)
    session.flush()
    return (session, client1)

class CreateClientTest(DatabaseTests):

    def test_createClient(self):
        (ses, client) = createClient()
        self.assertEqual(client.name, client.client_name)
```

DatabaseTest setup for tested code:

```
class DatabaseTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        super(DatabaseTests, self).setUp()
        from my.product import model
        from z3c.saconfig import Session
        from Products.Five import zcml
        from Products.Five import fiveconfigure
        import my.product.tests

        fiveconfigure.debug_mode = True
        zcml.load_config("configure.zcml", my.product.tests)
        fiveconfigure.debug_mode = False
        model.metadata.create_all(Session.bind, checkfirst=True)

    (def teardown omitted here)
```

configure.zcml for testing:

```
<configure xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
        xmlns:db="http://namespaces.zope.org/db">
<include package="z3c.saconfig" file="meta.zcml" />
<db:engine name="mydb" url="postgresql://pasd@localhost/mydb" />
<db:session engine="mydb" />
</configure>
```

The Plone site works. Postgresql db of mydb was setup and runs in the background. Unittest of tables works. But don't get why client1 instance was not created/recognized. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think your model is not connected to Session. Smells like import order problem, or you do not bind `BaseObject` to session in any point.

Comment: Agreed. (sorry reply this late) Back to drawing board on db connection - model-to-session. Thank you for taking the time.